# Sharing printer dari ubuntu ke windows

Tags: drivers

ada yg ingin saya tanyakan, kebetulan saya ada tugas membuat sharing printer dan saya memilih ubuntu 18.04 sebagai server dan windows 10 sebagai client..permasalahannya dri client tidak bisa connect dengan printer yg sdh disharing dari ubuntu? Saya masih noob, barangkali ada yg jauh lebih paham, itu sangat membantu..terimakasih
Atau ada konfigurasi samba dan cups untuk printer server, bisa berbagi

translate.google.com says you said:

I want to ask, I happen to have the task of making a sharing printer and I chose Ubuntu 18.04 as a server and Windows 10 as a client ... the problem is that the client cannot connect with the printer that has been shared from ubuntu? I am still a noob, maybe there are those who understand a lot more, it is very helpful ... thanks
Or there are configurations of samba and cups for the printer server, can be shared

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser on the Ubuntu system to open the CUPS admin interface at `http://localhost:631/admin` and ensure that both "Share printers connected to this system" and "Allow printing from the internet" are checked, thusly:

[image: CUPS admin page]

"Allow printing from the internet" should, in this case, be interpreted as "Allow printing from any computer that can send us a TCP/IP packet".

Or, google translated back to "Indonesian":

Gunakan browser pada sistem Ubuntu untuk membuka antarmuka admin CUPS di `http://localhost:631/admin` dan memastikan bahwa" Bagikan printer yang terhubung ke sistem ini "dan" Izinkan pencetakan dari internet "diperiksa, dengan demikian:

[! [Halaman admin CUPS] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEbPN.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEbPN.png)

"Izinkan pencetakan dari internet" harus, dalam hal ini, ditafsirkan sebagai "Izinkan pencetakan dari komputer mana pun yang dapat mengirimkan kami paket TCP/IP".